# How to insert image in UIWebview at caret position?

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, objective-c, xcode

This is the code I am currently using to insert an image, however, my webview loses its focus after the insertion made. But most oddly, I also have a notification set for keyboardWillShowNotification; and this notification is invoked after the insertion but no keyboard is present.

Can anyone give any solution on this problem?

```
//allow me to programmatically bring up keyboard
_changWeiBo.keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction = NO;
[_changWeiBo stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('content').focus()"];

[_changWeiBo stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.execCommand('insertImage', false, '%@')", imagePath]];

//disallow me to programmatically bring up keyboard
_changWeiBo.keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction = YES;
```

Comment: how are you inserting an image into a web view? are you using "`addSubview`" or something else?

Comment: This ruins the formatting. I am designing a rich text editor, it requires the image to intermingle with text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @alex-i, this solution below (enhanced by myself) perfectly solves the bug when user can't insert an image at caret postion because the UIWebview loses its focus when other views.

This is the most minimal working version to insert an image at caret position.

```
    this.prepareInsertImage = function(){
        try{
            backuprange();
        }
        catch(exc){
            log('prepareInsertImage: ' + exc);
        }
    }

    this.insertImage = function(imgPath){
        try{
            restorerange();
            document.execCommand("InsertImage",true,imgPath);
        }
        catch(exc){
            log('insertImage: ' + exc);
        }
    }
    var focusRange;
    function backuprange(){
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        focusRange = selection.getRangeAt(0);
        focusRange.setEnd(focusRange.startContainer, focusRange.startOffset);
    }
    function restorerange(){
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(focusRange);
    }
```

For anyone who wants to use this code in the future, simply call this:

```
    //Before UIImagePicker pops up
    [yourWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"prepareInsertImage()"];

    //After UIImagePicker selects a image and you edit and store the image elsewhere
    NSString* imagePath = @"the path for your image....";
    [yourWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insertImage('%@')",imagePath]];
```

Comment: this solution solved my problem perfectly. Before this I have tried a few methods (1. dynamically add img to html string and reload uiwebview to add the image, the problem is it would be difficult when insert image between styled texts 2. programming bring uiwebview to first responder after take photos, but it did not work out)

Answer (score 3):

I didn'tuse the `'insertImage'` command, sice I needed specific formatting of the image (in my case, the html will hold a thumb, when tapped will open in full screen). It should work correctly with the `insertImage` command as well. Here's the objective-c code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSAssert([[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage], @"Unhandled type: %@", [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType]);
    // this is just to gather some paths for the picked image
    [_rtDelegate richEditor:self saveImage:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] completion:^(NSString *thumbPath, NSString *largePath, CGSize thumbSize) {
        [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"docState.insertImage('%@', '%@', %d)", thumbPath, largePath, (int)thumbSize.height/2]];
    }];

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
-(void)onTapInsertPhoto:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender{
    [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"docState.prepareInsertImage();"];
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage];
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

    UIViewController *vc = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];
    [vc presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    [imagePicker release];
}
```

Here's the javascript (most important are the focusRange and backupRange):

```
this.prepareInsertImage = function(){
    try{
        backuprange();
    }
    catch(exc){
        log('prepareInertImage: ' + exc);
    }
}
this.insertImage = function(thumbPath, largePath, displayHeight){
    try{
        restorerange();
        // may work with the insertImage command here
        var imgwrap = document.createElement('a');
        imgwrap.href = largePath;
        imgwrap.setAttribute('href', 'rte:image:'+largePath);
        imgwrap.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'false');
        imgwrap.className = 'imgwrap';
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.setAttribute('src', thumbPath);
        img.setAttribute('height', displayHeight);
        imgwrap.appendChild(img);
        window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).insertNode(imgwrap);
    }
    catch(exc){
        log('insertImage: ' + exc);
    }
}
var focusRange;
function backuprange(){
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    focusRange = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    focusRange.setEnd(focusRange.startContainer, focusRange.startOffset);
}
function restorerange(){
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(focusRange);
}
```

You don't need 'docState' in the objective-c code, and 'this' in the javascript code - I used them because I have a class with more methods in javascript, which also holds some states.

Also note that `keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction` only works on iOS 6.0+, so previous iOS systems will not show the keyboard automatically (but still insert the image at the right position).

Comment: What does your _rtDelegate do? How do you make your function return with completion?

Comment: Hey sir, I want to pay you for this answer if i can! It works perfectly. Too bad I can't check your answer 100 times.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. The `_rtDelegate` from the code handles saving the picked image, and returns the path (in this case, also a thumb path) where it was stored.

Comment: Do you mind teaching me how to write a code with completion block?

Comment: window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).insertNode(imgwrap); What if I would like to insert the image into specific div. How do I do it?

Comment: In the example above it's getting wrapped into an `<a href>`element, same would go for a div. If you instead want to append them into a div, you'd have to get that div by its id: `var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDivId'); myDiv.appendChild(imgwrap);`. Regarding blocks: http://www.raywenderlich.com/9438/how-to-use-blocks-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2

Comment: This is a great answer. Vote up for more people to see it in the future!

Comment: Here is a new problem, the image is appended to the div. But I intend to insert image into where the caret is. I try to use this `var contentDiv = document.getElementById('content'); contentDiv.getRangeAt(0).appendChild(imgwrap);`sadly, the code failed to insert the image at correct position.

Comment: To be precise, it doesn't even insert.

Comment: in this case you should probably use `insertNode` and not `appendChild`, since the range is not a node. Not an expert on javascript, so can't say for sure.

Comment: Alex, check my new solution. I found a better way(aka execCommmand) to do the trick.